# Flask app error werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app.index'. Did you mean 'index' instead?

Tags: python, html, flask

i am trying to creat a site with flask but i am facing this error at the title.

I have one file named base.html that handle the links that i put until now.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FgVO.png)

And I have two files with routes, app.py and auth.py.
app.py[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJFxd.png)

auth.py[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rY7R.png)

Then the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCLOz.png)

I was not able to solve this, can you help me?

I expected to see the system that i am building.

Comment: Do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or paste the text into the question. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

Your links within the HTML template point to the identifier of route definitions within [Blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/blueprints/). Instead of using these, you create one instance of the Fask application per file. This cannot work.

Create ONE application instance and register a blueprint for each of the two files.
Within the `url_for` command you then refer to the name of the blueprint, followed by a period and the identifier of the endpoint.

To familiarize yourself with Flask, I suggest taking a look at the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/#) and [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).